# Androidx tests - How to set activity property before onCreate is called

Tags: android, testing, android-jetpack

i have a activity construct like this :

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var model: MyModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout)

    if (!this::model.isInitialized) {
        model = MyModel.newInstance(this)
    }

    model.functionToCall()
}}
```

I want to test MyActivity with mock as model.
Before **Androidx-tests** i use **Robolectric** (`ActivityBuilder`) to create a instance of MyActivity and set the model property with mock. In each test i start the activity lifecycle with `ActivityBuiler.setup()`.

With **Androidx-tests** i try to use `ActivityScenario` or `ActivityTestRule` but it was impossible to set model property **before this classes start the activity lifecycle**

How can i do with **Androidx-tests** to set `MyActivity.model` property with **mock** before onCreate is called ? I can't use Androidx tests ?

Thanks

Comment: unfortunately, if we can set `Lifecycle::State` as `ActivityScenario.launch` parameter we could pass `INITIALIZED` and manage activity before call complete lifecycle.

Comment: I am facing the same problem.. any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ActivityLifecycleMonitor. You can register a callback to get informed before activity goes into onCreate state. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/runner/lifecycle/ActivityLifecycleMonitor